# Why does VS Code produce a 'libhostpolicy.dylib' not found error running a project when VS for Mac successfully runs the same build output?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, maui

I have been developing a .NET MAUI app using VS for Mac. Following the end-of-life announcement for VS for Mac, I am trying to move development and testing across to VS Code using the C# Dev Kit and .Net MAUI extensions.

I have managed to get VS Code to successfully build the outputs for both ios and maccatalyst on arm64. However, when I try and run maccatalyst, for example, it produces the following error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.dylib' required to execute the application was not found in '/Users/ian/Projects/BitBucket/Ledger/Ledger/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64/'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
  - The application was run as a self-contained app because '/Users/ian/Projects/BitBucket/Ledger/Ledger/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64/Ledger.runtimeconfig.json' did not specify a framework.
  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, specify the appropriate framework in '/Users/ian/Projects/BitBucket/Ledger/Ledger/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64/Ledger.runtimeconfig.json'.
```

Both VS for Mac and VS Code produce identical Ledger.runtimeconfig.json files, a copy of which is shown below:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net7.0",
    "includedFrameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "7.0.13"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.MacCatalyst",
        "version": "16.4.7125"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.Maui.Core",
        "version": "**FromWorkload**"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.Maui.Controls",
        "version": "**FromWorkload**"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.Maui.Essentials",
        "version": "**FromWorkload**"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.VerifyOpenGenericServiceTrimmability": true,
      "System.AggressiveAttributeTrimming": true,
      "System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterInDesigntimeLicenseContextSerialization": false,
      "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsSupported": true,
      "System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Globalization.Invariant": false,
      "System.Net.Http.EnableActivityPropagation": false,
      "System.Net.Http.UseNativeHttpHandler": true,
      "System.Reflection.NullabilityInfoContext.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Resources.ResourceManager.AllowCustomResourceTypes": false,
      "System.Resources.UseSystemResourceKeys": false,
      "System.Runtime.InteropServices.BuiltInComInterop.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false,
      "System.StartupHookProvider.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Threading.Thread.EnableAutoreleasePool": true,
      "System.Text.Encoding.EnableUnsafeUTF7Encoding": false
    }
  }
}
```

Why can VS for Mac successfully start and run the maccatalyst app but VS Code cannot?

**Update**

Copy of the lauch.json file, referenced in a comment below, from which I use the Maccatalyst entry.

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET MAUI",
        "type": "maui",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "maui: Build"
    },
    {
        "name": "C#: Ledger.Tests",
        "type": "dotnet",
        "request": "launch",
        "projectPath": "${workspaceFolder}/UnitTests/Ledger.Tests.csproj",
        "launchConfigurationId": "TargetFramework=;Ledger.Tests"
    },
    {
        // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
        // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
        // For further information visit https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/blob/main/debugger-launchjson.md
        "name": "Maccatalyst",
        "type":  "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "targetArchitecture": "arm64",
        // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Ledger/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64/Ledger.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Ledger",
        // For more information about the 'console' field, see https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "stopAtEntry": false
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Please note that Visual Studio Code is a completely different product from Visual Studio for macOS. And both those are completely different from the Windows Visual Studio. Visual Studio Code is, in its code, just a plain text editor. It have plenty of plugins to make it a good editor for programming, but for that you need the right plugins, and a lot of editing of configuration files.

Comment: Have you ensured that both use the same development environment? Has vscode installed the corresponding extension pack?

Comment: I have reviewed the extensions in both VS and VSC and, while some entries are not available in both, I cannot see anything obvious missing. My understanding is the .NET MAUI extension provides the build, debug, and runtime support. I realize this is still in preview, but others must be able to execute their apps. I have reviewed the launch.json options and settings (see Update above) and cannot see anything remiss.

Comment: How do you execute the program in VSCODE? Compared to whether the command in VS for mac is missing.

Comment: In VS for Mac I select the maccatalyst target in debug mode and then start with or without debugging via either the run button or the debug menu option. In VSC I first select run and debug on the left-hand side menu, ensure maccatalyst target is selected, and then either start debugging or run without debugging from the Run menu.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when I try to debug a blank MAUI app with pressing F5 in vscode.

Although not 100% the same situation as you, what I did to resolve this error:

1. Ensure `.vscode/launch.json` has MAUI launch setting included. (Which you already did)

```
{
    "name": ".NET MAUI",
    "type": "maui",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "maui: Build"
},
```

2. Make sure the MAUI launch config has been selected in `RUN AND DEBUG` tab.

I can trigger breakpoints on both Android, iOS and macOS afterwards.

[image]

You can find Microsoft reference about debugging MAUI app in vscode [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-android&view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#debug-your-app)